# hadoop questoin regarding datatype

Tags: hadoop

Another Question from Cloudera sample exam

`Question 2
You need to write code to perform a complex calculation that takes several steps. You have decided to chain these jobs together and develop a custom composite class for the key that stores the results of intermediate calculations. Which interface must this key implement?
A. Writable
B. Transferable
C. CompositeSortable
D. WritableComparable`

I believe is D. WritableComparable.
In general what do I need to study for knowing more about the datatype of Hadoop Esco-system??

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933782/hadoop-questions, And yes the answer is writecomparable

Comment: I would suggest you to get a copy of Hadoop Definitive Guide.

Comment: Write some codes and get your hands dirty. I think that's the best way to learn.